# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable "channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]"

Tags: python

I am getting the above on the following code

```
def del_owner(p, i):
if i.host == p.config.owner_host:
    channel = i.sender
    hostname = i.group(2)

    conn = sqlite3.connect("aamnews.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Get channel's id
    c.execute("SELECT id FROM channels WHERE name=?", (channel,))
    channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Get chanel's owners
    c.execute("SELECT owners.hostname FROM owners INNER JOIN channel_owners ON owners.id=channel_owners.owner_id WHERE channel_id=?", (channel_id,))
    owners = [p.config.owner_host] + [e[0] for e in c.fetchall()]

    if hostname in owners:
        # Get owner_id
        c.execute("SELECT id FROM owners where hostname=?", (hostname,))
        owner_id = c.fetchone()[0]

        c.execute("DELETE FROM channel_owners WHERE owner_id=? AND channel_id=?", (owner_id, channel_id))

        # Check if owner has other channels
        c.execute("SELECT channel_id FROM channel_owners WHERE owner_id=?", (owner_id,))
        result = c.fetchone()

        if not result:
            c.execute("DELETE FROM owners WHERE id=?", (owner_id,))

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        return p.say("Deleted owner.")

    else:
        conn.close()
        return p.say("Owner doesn't exist.")
else:
    return p.say("Command is global owner only.")
```

It complains on line that has ==>   channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

I'm not sure how to handle and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is no such row, so `c.fetchone()` returns `None`.

Comment: You have no line with `feed_type = c.fetchone()[0]` in your posted code.

Comment: correction it should be channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

Comment: Does your SQL work in workbench? I suspect an error in the c.execute line.